# How to test failed PayPal transactions through Braintree SDK

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am using Braintree SDK on ASP.NET Core and I can create transactions using the access code generated from developers.paypal.com however all transactions are accepted by the payment processor and gateway.

I've tried to enter the magic amounts that are supposed to trigger declines as listed on the [Braintree documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/dotnet) however I think that they only work when you use a Braintree sandbox access token and not a PayPal sandbox access token (mentioned [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/dotnet#mocked-paypal-testing)). I've tried using an error code as an amount as documented on the PayPal API documentation [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errors/) but that was accepted as well as a valid amount and the transaction went through.

Do I have to sign up for a Braintree sandbox account and to be able to get one of the decline codes documented [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/processor-responses/authorization-responses)?

Comment: You stated earlier that you are using the Braintree SDK, can you clarify how you are implementing this without a Braintree Sandbox Account? (As this should provide you with the API keys/configuration needed in order to implement/integrate Braintree). If you are using Braintree to integrate with PayPal, you will need to sign up for a Braintree sandbox account in order to use the decline codes and link your [PayPal account](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/dotnet#linked-paypal-testing)

Comment: You can use access tokens generated from developers.paypal.com to use the Braintree SDK completely bypassing the need of signing up for a Braintree account. Braintree was acquired by PayPal.

Comment: Full Disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you need any further assistance, feel free to contact support. In this case to get decline codes, you'll want to use the mocked checkout flow and still will need to setup a Braintree sandbox.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to test the decline codes unless I sign up for the sandbox account at Braintree. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full Disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you need any further assistance, feel free to contact support.</sub>

If you are using the PayPal access codes, in order to receive the decline codes, you'll want to use the mocked checkout flow and will need to setup a Braintree sandbox.